# How does the concept of the electron shell (also called energy level) and the orbital coexist?

Tags: orbitals, atomic-structure

Running into a bit of confusion trying to understand the atomic structure and the root cause is mostly related to orbitals and energy levels.

At a basic level, I was taught that electrons orbit the nucleus in fixed, circular orbits called “electron shells.” New information that I’ve learned states that there is some uncertainty in the positions of electrons at a given time. For example, although the one electron in a Hydrogen atom orbits the nucleus at the first energy level, its position is uncertain, that is, it can be further away from the nucleus or much closer.

To show where electrons are most likely to be found, orbitals are used which depict a region in which an electron will be 90% of the time.

The problem in my understanding lies with energy levels. The first energy level has an orbital called 1s and has a spherical shape with the nucleus at its center. How could an electron be classified as being in the first energy level when it’s possible that it can be found right near the nucleus? Similarly, the second energy level contains a spherical orbital as well called 2s. How could we say an electron is at the second energy level when it can very well be found much lower than that energy level according to the 2s orbital? It’s hard to see how orbitals and energy levels exist at once: one says an electron can be found near the nucleus whilst the other says it must be orbiting in the second energy level.

I’d greatly appreciate it if the explanation is sufficient enough for an As level student.

Comment: There are no circular orbit for electrons. Electrons have no orbit, no movement, no speed. If they had a movement, they would progressively loose their energy by radiation, and finally fall on the nucleus. Apparently you have never heard about Schrödinger equation, eigenfunctions and eigenvalues. This is necessary to understand what is an electron, an orbital, and the energy associated to this orbital. I could of course explain it to you. But this would take time. And it is quite a whole chemistry course that would be required to develop all this theory. So I stop here. Unfortunately.

Comment: Welcome to the strange world of quantum mechanics! Although not zero, the probability of the electron striking the nucleus is very small, in part because the nucleus is very small. But it is not zero and when it happens it can trigger a transformation of the nucleus: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_capture This was studied by Luis Alvarez, won a Nobel prize for this work. His son happened to lay down the foundation for the currently accepted theory explaining the extinction of the dinosaurs.

Comment: Mathematically, the probability of finding the electron at one point is vanishingly small, due to the delocalized ("uncertain distribution") nature of the wavefunction (a name for the function that describes an orbital). Uncertainty in quantum mechanics is a strange thing, by the way, not quite the same as we are usually familiar with.

Comment: @Maurice If electrons did not have speed then there would not be needed relativistic corrections in relativistic quantum chemistry. Nonrelativistic prediction of Hg melting point is +80 deg C. Relativistic one is about -38/-39 deg C. Aside of that Schr. wave eq. model of H atom starts with the classical model of energy of charged particle (1/2mv^2 - e^2/(4.pi.eps0.r) near a central quadratic force.

Comment: @Poutnik. When I say that the electron has no speed, it does not mean that its speed is zero. It means that the electron has no speed at all, a little like the fact that an electron has no religion. If the electron has no speed, it still has a kinetic energy, and this kinetic energy is sensitive to relativistic effects. This kinetic energy is not (1/2)mv^2. No, after Schrödinger, the kinetic energy is the second derivate of the wave function multiplied by constants.

Comment: @Maurice But that is rather the consequence of using Hamiltonian mechanics instead of the Newton one. In the latter, E_k=0.5mv^2. In the former, v=sqrt(2E_k/m)  (all nonrelativistically, in Sch.Eq. context)

Comment: @Poutnik. Your definition of E and v are similar. But in fact, the electron has no speed. It is not sqrt(2E_k/m) as written in your comment. It is not any other formula. Electron has no speed at all. So it has no use to calculate something that does not exist.

Comment: Funny thing is Dirac admitted relativistic corrections for electrons in light atoms are not needed because their speed is about 0.01c.

Comment: I agree, Dirac and also Pekka Pyykkö were able to state that the speed of the electron was much smaller than $c$. But this speed is not related to a point (x,y,z) like in Newtonian mechanics.

Answer (score 1):

There always coexist several models for historical and educational reasons. Especially  the latter is based on several levels of trade off between accuracy and simplicity.

If we take mechanical work:

- I was taught in elementary school physics lessons $W=F \cdot L$.
- I was taught in high school physics lessons $W=F \cdot L \cdot  \cos{\text{(alpha)}}$.
- I was taught in university physics lessons $W=\int_{L}{\vec{F}\cdot \text{d}\vec{L}}$.

The electron shell education model is based on obsolete Rutherford and Bohr atomic models, with simple energy levels indexed by natural numbers. The notion of orbits and shells is easily understandable by young students.

For a hydrogen atom, energy levels for the same main quantum number $n$ ($\text{1s}$),($\text{2s 2p}$), ($\text{3d 3p 3d}$)... are almost exactly the same (Originally thought the same but there are slight deviations explained later).

For atoms with more than one electrons, energies of "sub shells" $\text{s, p, d, f}$ differ and the concept of energy shells $n=1,2,3,4,..$ breaks down. Energy levels further differ even withing sub shells in presence of external electromagnetic fields.

The orbital model is based on more advanced quantum mechanics, using solving of Schroedinger wave equations of electrons. Orbitals can be understood in three different but related meanings as:

- orbital(1) as a particular solution of the above equation, introducing particular integer parameters $n$,$l$,$m_\text{l}$ as "quantum numbers".
- orbital(2) as a particular quantum state of an electron, described by orbital(1).
- orbital(3) as 3D region with probable ooccurance of electrons, described by orbital(1) and orbital(2).

There is one important fact. Orbitals(3) as 3D regions in large extent overlap. Purely mathematically, considering probability density converging to zero in infinity, they fully overlap.

It means, no point around a nucleus belongs to a particular orbit nor a particular energy level nor a particular orbital. Electrons from any orbital can occur at any point, but with different probabilities (with exception of 3D node surfaces where their probability of occurrence is zero).